# Bash `echo` regular expression to move the caret to the end of the previous line

Tags: regex, ascii, echo, prompt

Are there any character codes that I can use in the `echo -e` regular expression to move the caret around?

I want to have an echo and a the user to continue writing (using `read`) in the same line with the echo:

```
echo "Test: " ; echo -e "<RegExp to move caret>" ; read $VAR
```

Such that the result will look like:

```
Test: user input
```

Instead if

```
Test: 
user input
```

Is this possible only with `echo` and `read`?

Answer (score 2):

Why make it complicated, you can directly use `read` like this:

```
read -p "Test: " VAR
```

that will display:

```
Test: <user input>
```

in the same line.

Comment: Thanks! That is what I was trying but did not know about -p. Well, this does not answer to the question actually but is solved my problem so I only vote up.

Comment: You're welcome. If this answer helped you solve your problem, please consider marking it as "accepted", so users facing a similar problem in the future will be able to see it easily.